# with xhtml documnent , how do one trigger quirk mode?

Tags: quirks-mode

With the Xhtml document , how do you trigger quirk mode in internet explorer?
is it related to meta tag or doc type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support XHTML. In order to be XHTML it must be served with the `application/xhtml+xml` content-type, but IE doesn't support that. If you use `text/html` it will be parsed as HTML regardless of DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you don't specify a `DOCTYPE` most modern browsers will render the page in quirks mode. You can also "trigger" quirks mode by using `xhtml1-transitional` as your `DOCTYPE`. [See this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

There was a bug in IE6 that caused quirks mode to be triggered if you put an xml declaration or white spaces before the `DOCTYPE`, but that was fixed in IE7.